# Assigning the variables to the Temporary table columns

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm working on a Task where I should get the datas from all the table from the Database without knowing the table names. What I'm planning to do is to write a query to get all the table names and column names and store it in a temporary table.

Once I got the table name and column name I have to store the values to the variables like `@Table_Name` and `@Column_Name`. Then I have to call the table names within a Loop and have to write a query like this

```
"select * from '''+@Table_Name+''' where '''+@Column_Name+''' = 1"
```

Earlier I used `cursor` to get the values and store it in a variable and call it within the loop. But it seems that the cursor is consuming more time and memory. So I thought of changing it using temporary table.

My doubt is, is it possible to assign the Temporary table values to a variable to use it later. If possible how to do it?

Comment: How does this query make sense? Many tables' columns' values will not be convertible to `int`, and yet the `WHERE` clause will force such an attempt to be made.

Comment: I just mentioned col_val '1' for an example. THe actual column value is declared in nvarchar

Comment: The Column name will always be the same with nvarchar value like EngUID or EngID. The table name is one which changes. Sorry I wasnt clear about ur question when I replied.,

Answer (score 0):

Your idea may not work, I feel, since you are trying to incorporate the concept of arrays in SQL Server. SQL Server does not have arrays, but it has tables. You can obtain the data you need by creating a temporary table. Inserting into it by firing a query like 
`select * from sys.tables`.
Then trying to do your operation by loading each row from this table. After your work is done, by all means drop the table.